# Implementing Minimax Algorithm for Tic-Tac-Toe in C++

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've been working on a C++ implementation of a Tic-Tac-Toe Minimax AI and I'm struggling to force the AI to play moves to block the player from winning. I was hoping some people can help me by finding out how to enforce this.

**Node Code**

```
void Node::addToNodeList(int turn) {
  childNodes.push_back(Node(G));
  for (auto& child : childNodes) {
    child.addToNodeList(-turn);

    if (child.childNodes.empty()) {
      float tempScore = child.determineMinimaxValue();

      if (tempScore < score) {
        score = tempScore;
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < child.childNodes.size(); i++) {
        if (child.childNodes[i].score < score) {
          score = child.childNodes[i].score;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

float Node::determineMinimaxValue()
{
  if (childNodes.empty()) {
    if (G.getWinner() == 0) {
      return 0.f;
    } else if (G.getWinner() == -1) {
      return -1.f;
    } else if (G.getWinner() == 1) {
      return 1.f;
    }
  } else {
    for (auto& child : childNodes) {
      child.determineMinimaxValue();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**AI Player Code**

```
Node AIPlayer::minimaxMove(int player, GameBoard GB)
{
  G = GB;
  N = Node(G); 
  N.addToNodeList(player);
  return N;
}

int AIPlayer::makeTheMove(GameBoard *GB, Node ND)
{
  float smallest = 100;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ND.childNodes.size(); i++) {
    smallest = std::min(smallest, ND.childNodes[i].score);

    if (i == ND.childNodes.size() - 1) {
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < ND.childNodes.size(); j++) {
        if (smallest == ND.childNodes[j].score) {
          for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
              for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                GB->playerBox[x][y][z] = ND.childNodes[j].G.playerBox[x][y][z];
                GB->winCondition[x][y][z] = ND.childNodes[j].G.winCondition[x][y][z];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: ya, filter your code thru `indent` and then we can talk.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I did mark as Incomplete. Was called away before I could finish so hopefully I've fixed the indentation now and finished the code call.

Comment: @Raisus What heuristic function are you using?

Comment: @TejasPatel The heuristic function is "determineMinimaxValue"; which sets up the heuristic value to be +1 at the nodes where the human player has won. 0 at the nodes where the game is drawn and -1 at the nodes where the AI player has won. The second half of "addToNodeList" adds all the scores of child nodes up, then divides by the number of child nodes to get a score relevant to the overall score of its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the answer to this by using a little bit of help from my tutor and some liberal use of `for (auto &child : childNodes)`

**Node Code**

```
void Node::addToNodeList(int turn) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      //for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        if (G.playerBox[i][j][1] == 0) {
          G.playerBox[i][j][1] = turn;
          G.winCondition[i][j][1] = true;

          childNodes.push_back(Node(G));

          G.playerBox[i][j][1] = 0;
          G.winCondition[i][j][1] = false;
        }
      //}
    }
  }

for (auto &child : childNodes) {
  child.addToNodeList(-turn);

  if (child.childNodes.empty()) {
    int tempScore = child.determineMinimaxValue();

    if (tempScore < score) {
      score = tempScore;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (turn == -1) {
      int smallest = 100000;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->childNodes.size(); i++) {
        smallest = std::min(smallest, this->childNodes[i].score);
      }
      score = smallest;
    }
    else {
      int biggest = -100000;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->childNodes.size(); i++) {
        biggest = std::max(biggest, this->childNodes[i].score);
      }
    score = biggest;
    }
  }
}

int Node::determineMinimaxValue() {
  if (G.getWinner() == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (G.getWinner() == -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (G.getWinner() == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**AI Player Code**

```
Node AIPlayer::minimaxMove(int player, GameBoard GB) {
  G = GB;
  N = Node(G); 
  N.addToNodeList(player);
  return N;
}

int AIPlayer::makeTheMove(GameBoard *GB, Node ND) {
  if (GB->getWinner() == 1 || GB->getWinner() == -1) {
    return 1;
  }

  int smallest = 100000;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ND.childNodes.size(); i++) {
    smallest = std::min(smallest, ND.childNodes[i].score);
  }

  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < ND.childNodes.size(); j++) {
    if (smallest == ND.childNodes[j].score) {
      for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
          for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
            GB->playerBox[x][y][z] = ND.childNodes[j].G.playerBox[x][y][z];
            GB->winCondition[x][y][z] = ND.childNodes[j].G.winCondition[x][y][z];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```